# Symfony 2 - actions to save data with one to one relationship

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to Symfony 2. So pardon me if this is a simple problem but I just can't figure it out how to deal with it.

I have 2 entities called Book and Page.

This is the snippet of Book entity code

```
/**
 * Book
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="`book`")
 */
class Book {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="`id`", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="`name`", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    ...
}
```

And this is the snippet for my Page entity

```
/**
 * Page
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="`page`")
 */
class Page {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="`id`", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Book")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="`book_id`", referencedColumnName="`id`")
     */
    private $book;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="`page_number`", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     */
    private $pageNumber;

    ...
}
```

I am currently using PosgreSQL as my RDBMS.

Creating and saving data into Book table is fine. But when it comes to saving data for the Page, I need to make it reference to a Book by book id. The book is already stored in the database.

I know that the old school way is to pass the book id as hidden field into the Page form.
I am just wondering, is this the right way to do in Symfony?

What I have tried is that I pass a GET request to the page create action.
Something along the line of

```
http://sites/page/create?bookId=123
```

And the appropriate action on the Page controller is:

```
class PageController extends Controller {

    public function createAction(Request $request) {

        // Check if bookId has been passed
        $bookId = $request->get('bookId');

        // Find the book by its $bookId
        $book = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("MyBundle:Book")->find($bookId);

        // Create new page
        $page = new Page();

        // Assign the book to the page
        $page->setBook($book);

        // Create the page form
        $pageForm = $this->createForm(
             new PageType(),
             $page
        );

        $pageForm->handleRequest($request);
        if ($pageForm->isValid()) {
            $pageData = $pageForm->getData();

            // SAVE DATA HERE

            // Redirect to index page
            return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('index_page'));

        }

        // Then render to the template
        return $this->render(
            'MyBundle:Page:index.html.twig',
            array('form' => $pageForm->createView())
        );
    }
}
```

And my page type is:

```
class PageType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder->add('page_number', 'text', array(
                                                'label'    => 'Page Number',
                                                'required' => true,
                                            )
        );

        $builder->add('content', 'textarea', array(
                                                'label'    => 'Page Content',
                                                'required' => false,

                                            )
        );

        $builder->add('save', 'submit', array(
                                                'label'    => 'Save',
                                                'attr'     => array('class' => 'btn')
                                            ));


    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Page'
        ));
    }

    ...
}
```

My issue is that:

1. Is this the right way to deal with creating entities that has one to one relationship with another entity?
2. When I did my way above, it seems like when I submit the form, I don't get the book entity anymore. What is wrong?

I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction regarding creating an entity that has one to one relationship with another entity.
And if there is anything wrong with the code, could someone please point it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was:

To create entities that has one to one relationship with another entity, I use REST way to design the URL like below (where 123 is the bookId)

```
http:sites/page/create/123
```

I have also changed my createAction on PageController to receive $bookId instead of $request.
It look something like below.

```
class PageController extends Controller {

    public function createAction($bookId) {

        // Find the book by its $bookId
        $book = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("MyBundle:Book")->find($bookId);

        // Create new page
        $page = new Page();

        // Assign the book to the page
        $page->setBook($book);

        // Create the page form
        $pageForm = $this->createForm(
             new PageType(),
             $page
        );

        $pageForm->handleRequest($request);
        if ($pageForm->isValid()) {
           $pageData = $pageForm->getData();

           // SAVE DATA HERE

           // Redirect to index page
           return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('index_page'));

        }

        // Then render to the template
        return $this->render(
            'MyBundle:Page:index.html.twig',
            array('form' => $pageForm->createView())
        );
    }
}
```

To get it to pass $bookId into my createAction, I have define the routing to be:

```
page_create:
    pattern:  /page/create/{bookId}
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Page:create }
    requirements:
        bookId: \d+
```

Thanks to Wing for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

your codes have same issue:

(1)Every form needs to know the name of the class that holds the underlying data [(Symfony doc)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes)

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task',
    ));
}
```

(2)form field name must same as entity field name

Comment: Hi Wing, apologies.. my PageType has that function but I forget to show it. I have edited the code.

Comment: I am wondering, is passing the book id by GET request is the right way to do this??

Comment: Yes !! but , forgot to say with you , you can follow REST(Representational State Transfer) to design you url  (Example:http://sites/page/create/123)

Comment: Thanks, Wing. In the end, I go with the REST to design my URL like what you have suggested.